# C# how to find xml doc child record count

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a xml in below both formats

**format 1**

```
<a>
  <b/>
</a>
```

**format 2**

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <c1>Data</c1>
      <c2>Data1</c2>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>
```

How can I write c# code to see is c record exist or not and if exist how can take a count of c record?

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And tell us what you'd expect to get in your two cases. I'm guessing `0` from format 1 and `1` from format 2 (but I wouldn't be surprised if I'm wrong

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky this is not a debugging question and hence OP does not need to provide a [MRE]... They may want to show it anyway to "demonstrate research" - lack of code is just a reason to get post downvoted, and not a requirement for non-debugging posts.

Answer (score 2):

Using `XDocument` you can do something like this. `Count` will return the number of child elements or 0 if no elements was found.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

var format1 = """
    <a>
      <b/>
    </a>
    """;

var format2 = """
    <a>
      <b>
        <c>
          <c1>Data</c1>
          <c2>Data1</c2>
        </c>
      </b>
    </a>
    """;

Console.WriteLine(Count(format1, "c")); // Prints 0
Console.WriteLine(Count(format2, "c")); // Prints 2

int Count(string xml, string elementName)
{
    var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var count = document.Descendants(elementName).Elements().Count();
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will find what you want from a `XElement`

```
static int FindC(XElement root)
{
    return root
        .Elements("b")
        .SelectMany(n => n.Elements("c"))
        .SelectMany(n => n.Elements())
        .Count();
}
```

Use it by first parsing the XML into `XDocument`, then passing `document.Root`

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Parse(yourXml);
var count = FindC(doc.Root);
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hcy12p)

You can also use XPath. For example:

```cs
var countOfAnyC = xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElements("//c").Count();
var countOfABC = xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElements("/a/b/c").Count();
```